# no records found in my jsf page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to retrive data from my database and it actually worked for another table but with this one there is only no records found without any error message in the log file here is my code :

```
                        @ManagedBean
                  @SessionScoped
     public class AnnonceBean implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private List<SelectItem> anonItems;
private DataModel annonces;
private Annonce newAnnonce = new Annonce();
private Annonce editAnnonce;
private DaoAnnonce aDao = new DaoAnnonce();

public List<SelectItem> getAnonItems() {
    if (anonItems == null) {
        anonItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        List<Annonce> annList = aDao.selectAll();
        for (Annonce an : annList) {
            anonItems.add(new SelectItem((Annonce) an, ((Annonce) an)
                    .getTitre()));
            anonItems.add(new SelectItem((Annonce) an, ((Annonce) an)
                    .getContenu()));
            anonItems.add(new SelectItem((Annonce) an, ((Annonce) an)
                    .getProfesseur().getPrenom()));

        }
    }
    return anonItems;
}

public AnnonceBean() {
    if (annonces == null) {
        annonces = new ListDataModel();
        annonces.setWrappedData(aDao.selectAll());
    }
}

public String creer() {
    return "add";
}

public String create() {
    aDao.ajouter(newAnnonce);
    newAnnonce = new Annonce();
    annonces.setWrappedData(aDao.selectAll());
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Ajout effectué avec succés");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    return "list";

}

public String deleteGroupe() {
    Annonce a = (Annonce) annonces.getRowData();
    aDao.supprimer(a);
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Suppression effectué avec succés");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    return null;
}

public String editAnnonce() {
    editAnnonce=(Annonce)annonces.getRowData();
    return "edit";
}
public String updateAnnonce(){
    aDao.modifier(editAnnonce);
    annonces.setWrappedData(aDao.selectAll());
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Modification effectué avec succés");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    return "list";
}
```

and this is my Dao class code

```
              public class DaoAnnonce {
private static final String JPA_UNIT_NAME="Portail";
private EntityManager entityManager;
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if (entityManager == null) {
        entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                JPA_UNIT_NAME).createEntityManager();
    }
    return entityManager;
}

 public   void ajouter(Annonce a)
    {
        EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        entityManager.persist(a);
        tx.commit();

    }
 public void modifier(Annonce a)
    {
        EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        entityManager.merge(a);
        tx.commit();

    }
 public  void supprimer(Annonce a)
    {


        EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        a=entityManager.merge(a); // important
        entityManager.remove(a);
        tx.commit();

    }
 public List<Annonce > selectAll() {
        List<Annonce > annonces =getEntityManager().createQuery("select a from Annonce  a").getResultList();
        return annonces;
    }
```

and this the jsf code

```
                    <p:tab title="Annonces">
            <p:dataTable var="annonce" value="#{annonceBean.annonces}"
                editable="true">

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{tableBean.onEdit}" />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{tableBean.onCancel}" />

                <p:column headerText="Titre" style="width:30%">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{annonce.titre}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{annonce.titre}" style="width:100%" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Contenu" style="width:20%">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{annonce.contenu}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{annonce.contenu}" style="width:100%"
                                label="contenu" />
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Professeur" style="width:24%">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{annonce.prenom}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{annonce.prenom}" style="width:100%"
                                label="prenom" />

                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:tab>
```

I am working on eclipse and i am using primefaces for the components

Comment: Have you verified that your query is actually returning results?

Answer (score 0):

In your bean `AnnonceBean` there is no method called `getAnnonces()`, but there is a method `getAnonItems()` returning a `List<SelectItem>` which is probably what you want. If this is the case, `#{annonceBean.annonces}` should be replaced by `#{annonceBean.anonItems}`.

Comment: still dosen't work and the annonces does exist i did declare it in the managed Bean

Comment: @MeknessiHamida I don't understand why you are using `List<SelectItem>` you will probably only need `List<Annonce>`... and no there is no `getAnnonces()` in your question, verify again.

Comment: I didn't mention the getters and setters but it does exist in my code

Comment: In that case you should break right after the line `List<Annonce > annonces =getEntityManager().createQuery("select a from Annonce  a").getResultList();` to see if there is content inside `annonces`. If not, try your query directly with a database client. If yes, verify the package import for `ManagedBean`.